# Configuring MySQL server connection in SmartFoxServer

Tags: mysql, jdbc, smartfoxserver

I have been trying to connect to mysql via JDBC in `config.xml`.

I've changed  default values to proper values like below :

```
<DatabaseManager active="true">


        <Driver>org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</Driver>
        <ConnectionString>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mysql</ConnectionString>

        <UserName>root</UserName>
        <Password></Password>

        <TestSQL><![CDATA[SELECT NOW()]]></TestSQL>

        <MaxActive>10</MaxActive>
        <MaxIdle>10</MaxIdle>

        <OnExhaustedPool>fail</OnExhaustedPool>
        <BlockTime>5000</BlockTime>

</DatabaseManager>
```

But when i try to start SmartFoxServer, get following errors :

```
        DB Manager Activated ( org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver )
Can't load db driver: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
11:13:16.054 - [ SEVERE ] > DbManager could not retrive a connection. java.sql.S
QLException: Configuration file not found
it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.exceptions.DbManagerException: The Test SQL statem
ent failed! Please check your configuration.
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.SmartFoxServer.setupZone(SmartFoxServer
.java:1843)
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.lib.ConfigReader.parse_Zones(ConfigRead
er.java:806)
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.lib.ConfigReader.readZoneConfig(ConfigR
eader.java:174)
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.SmartFoxServer.initServerSocket(SmartFo
xServer.java:339)
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.SmartFoxServer.run(SmartFoxServer.java:
607)
Problems in config file: The Test SQL statement failed! Please check your config
uration.
it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.exceptions.ConfigurationException: The Test SQL st
atement failed! Please check your configuration.
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.lib.ConfigReader.readZoneConfig(ConfigR
eader.java:199)
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.SmartFoxServer.initServerSocket(SmartFo
xServer.java:339)
        at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.SmartFoxServer.run(SmartFoxServer.java:
607)

Errors found in configuration files.
Unable to start the server.


Shutting down server...

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Should copy MySQL Connector/J in :

```
C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
```

to :

```
C:\Users\username\SmartFoxServerPRO_1.6.6\jre\lib\ext\
```

And then restart SFS.

It worked like a charm. Good Luck.